# How to manage users in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

I have managed to get Active Directory Auth working on my SharePoint environment. Now, I need to get User Management working for Active Directory. i.e. I want to add, delete & modify user profiles from within SharePoint. Is it possible?

For FBA users, I had installed an addon, http://strepas.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/fba-2010-utility-update/, which let me do the same thing from Site Settings under 'Manage FBA users'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the profile sync set up to replicate back to AD if you want to be able to manage information in SharePoint.  See the definitive work from [Spence Harbar](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx).

Comment: Thx. Assuming that Profile sync is in place, How can I create new/manage users from within SharePoint UI?